# Formatting issue with too many spaces being returned in a SELECT Query

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I asked a previous question the other day about adding a new column that returns a date two days after. I am now getting the results I need, however the spacing between the two dates (the original and the date plus 2) is returning 109 characters and I can't for the life of me figure out how to return it with only a few spaces between.

The format of the original SELECT statement is fine, however after the ,lastupdate + 2 is where the issue lays I believe.

I've attempted to put the same "||'    '||" format between the "e.lastupdate, e.lastupdate + 2", but the query fails to run when this happens. It returns an "Invalid Number" error.

```
select p.id||'    '||p.lastname||'    '||p.firstname||'    '|| e.lastupdate, e.lastupdate + 2
from table p, othertable e

where p.id = e.id 
and hold = 8 
and id in (
select id from othertable 
where buildinginfo is null
) 
order by id;
```

Actual Results (Not showing correct on StackOverflow, but there's 109 spaces between 05-SEP-18 and 07-SEP-18):

```
000000000    Scott    Michael    05-SEP-18                                                                                                         07-SEP-18
```

Expected Results:

```
000000000    Scott    Michael    05-SEP-18    07-SEP-18
```

Comment: Check if this works for you: `select p.id||'    '||p.lastname||'    '||p.firstname||'    '|| e.lastupdate||'    '||e.lastupdate + 2
from table p, othertable e

where p.id = e.id 
and hold = 8 
and id in (
select id from othertable 
where buildinginfo is null
) 
order by id;`

Comment: Thank you for responding Antonio. When I attempt this query, it doesn't actually run. It returns the "Invalid Number" error message on TOAD

Comment: Strange, did you try to put a TRIM call around the dates?

Comment: Hi OldProgrammer. I'm a bit confused about the syntax of this, as I've never used it before. Would it be possible to put a TRIM(', '), or is this not the correct format? I believe the comma as the delimiter is what is causing this massive gap

Comment: I've been reading about the || and it seems very simple: it's just to concatenate strings. [|| operator](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat2.php). I don't use Oracle, or toad, but as i understand, my last comment should work. You could try [TRIM](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php), as @OldProgrammer told you.

Comment: I think what OldProgrammer was talking about is something like this: `select p.id||'    '||p.lastname||'    '||p.firstname||'    '|| TRIM(e.lastupdate), TRIM(e.lastupdate + 2)
from table p, othertable e

where p.id = e.id 
and hold = 8 
and id in (
select id from othertable 
where buildinginfo is null
) 
order by id;`

Comment: Appreciate ya'lls help on this! I actually got it solved by just putting the "e.lastupdate + 2" into parenthesis. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Ended up putting a parenthesis around the "e.lastupdate +2" and it actually ran!

```
select p.id||' '||p.lastname||' '||p.firstname||' '|| e.lastupdate||' '||
       (e.lastupdate + 2) 
from table p, othertable e 
where p.id = e.id 
and hold = 8 
and id in 
         ( select id from othertable
           where buildinginfo is null ) 
order by id;
```

Comment: Your `e.lastupdate` is a number, not a string, so you should wrap TO_CHAR() around it to format it as appropriate. Oracle does that automatically and is probably padding it with too many spaces for some reason.